# PyInstaller InputError

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I found PyInstaller and after making the exe file and running it, I'm getting those errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "window.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "tracker.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "listener.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
ImportError
[6340] Failed to execute script main
```

window.py, listener.py, and tracker.py. Those are my python scripts. At first, I was getting errors like "Module name 'cassiopeia' missing" <- which I fixed but typing 'pip install cassiopeia', then there was a similar problem, but with 'pynput' which I fixed the same way and now I'm here stuck. I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through internet, I've found a solution:

Latest pynput doesn't like PyInstaller, so everything what I had to do was uninstall pynput and install pynput==1.6.8